# Jrebel configuration for WebLogic14 maven

Tags: maven-plugin, jrebel, weblogic14c

We have recently switched from Weblogic 12 to 14 and in WL 12 we were using JRebel by setting Java Options in WebLogic startup bat file e.g:

```
set REBEL_HOME=%VIEW_HOME%\...\jrebel5
if exist "%VIEW_HOME%\...\jrebel5\jrebel.jar" set REBEL_HOME=%VIEW_HOME%\...\jrebel5

if exist %REBEL_HOME%\jrebel.jar (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=-noverify -javaagent:%REBEL_HOME%\jrebel.jar -DAPP_HOME=%APP_HOME% %JAVA_OPTIONS%
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Drebel.log=true !JAVA_OPTIONS!
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Drebel.metro_plugin=true !JAVA_OPTIONS!
)
```

But now since we are starting the WebLogic via maven and it is added as a dependency in pom, so I can't find a way to activate the JRebel for our application.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To activate JRebel standalone you have two options, either to use the activation wizard or to use the command line tool.

You can start the activation utility by running `activate-gui.sh` script in a *nix environment. When using Windows, run `activate-gui.cmd`. The JRebel Activation wizard will open. This window contains two tabs – **Try JRebel for FREE** and **I already have a license**.

Additionally, the **bin** directory contains a script that can be used for license activation via the command line, i.e. in headless environment. To activate from command line, start the activation utility by running **activate.sh** script in *nix environment or **activate.cmd** in Windows environment.

```
$> ./activate.sh <file>|<URL>|<activation-code>|<email>
```

Specifying the user email is required when activating with a license server URL

You can find more instructions on how to activate standalone applications from the JRebel manual: https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/activate.html

If you have any other questions, then I recommend contacting our support at **support-rebel@perforce.com**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my issue is not to activate JRebel for an IDE rather my externally running WebLogic server.